# Get cookies set by Java in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, cookies

I am trying to set cookies using java as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html).

I want to use this cookie in javascript (due to some constraints need to use it like this only). But I am not able to see any cookies set (for that I am using [web developer addon firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/)).

Is there a way to do this? Is this kind of cookie usage even possible?

Java code:

```
try {
            // instantiate CookieManager
            CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
            CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();

            // create cookie
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserName", str);

            // add cookie to CookieStore for a
            // particular URL
            URL url = new URL("http://host.example.com");
            cookieJar.add(url.toURI(), cookie);
            System.out.println("Added cookie using cookie handler");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to set cookie using CookieHandler");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Javascript:

```
function Cookie(cname){
    alert("in getcookie function");
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    console.log(document.cookie);
    //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="somewhere something went wrong!";
}
</script>

<div id="result">
    <p onclick="Cookie('JSESSIONID')">Click me</p>
</div>
```

The console.log did not show any output.

Comment: Could you provide the [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you are using ?

Comment: if you do `console.log(document.cookie)` in your rendered document, what does it show?

Comment: Empty output. @MichaelDibbets

Comment: Okay, that means your cookie isn't getting set, or you are sending out your headers before you are setting your cookies. btw, you might want to use this simpler code for your cookies :-) http://jsfiddle.net/mdibbets/jfpu45nx/1 it returns them as an object. Please check your code paths that you call your cookie code as early in page generation as possible. The moment you are outputting to the browsers the cookies need to be have been set already.

Comment: Here I am calling the function by onclick, that too after seeing the java code's output "cookie created."  I have used ur code and the string in the object is "undefined". does this mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
    import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("uniqueFileId" + uniqueFileId, uniqueFileId);
    cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 10);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setSecure(false);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: There is no servlet response in my code. It is Java code not Servlet.